# docker run registry error 301 response missing Location header

Tags: docker, docker-registry

i am getting the following error (see execution command below):

```
DEBU[0000] using "text" logging formatter               
panic: Get : 301 response missing Location header

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/docker/distribution/registry/handlers.NewApp(0x7f5f7ba3eab8, 0xc2080cf1a0, 0xc20802b8a0, 0x3, 0xc20802b8d8, 0x5, 0xc20802b908, 0x4, 0xc2080ce720, 0xa5e630, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/registry/handlers/app.go:81 +0x5eb
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/cmd/registry/main.go:62 +0x439

goroutine 6 [syscall]:
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/src/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:21 +0x1f
created by os/signal.init·1
    /usr/src/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:27 +0x35

goroutine 10 [runnable]:
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc20809d6b0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/http/transport.go:928 +0x9ce
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/src/go/src/net/http/transport.go:660 +0xc9f

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/src/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 11 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc20809d6b0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/http/transport.go:945 +0x41d
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/src/go/src/net/http/transport.go:661 +0xcbc
```

i am starting docker registry as follows:

```
docker run \
  --rm -it \
  --env="REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY=SECRET_KEY" \
  --env="REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY=ACCESS_KEY" \
  --env="REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET=bucket" \
  --env="REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/certs/domain.crt" \
  --env="REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/certs/domain.key" \
  --env="REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=localhost:5000" \
  --name="registry" \
  --publish="5000:5000" \
  --volume="/sandbox/docker/certs:/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/certs" \
  --volume="/sandbox/docker/registry/config.yml:/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/cmd/registry/config.yml" \
  distribution/registry cmd/registry/config.yml
```

where `REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY`, `REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY`, and `REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET` holding dummy values for security reasons. i am able to use them to write\read from the desired s3 bucket.

here are some more information:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 0
Images: 109
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 109
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-53-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.54 GiB
Name: heaven
ID: REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY_REASONS
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

directory structure:

```
$ ls -R /sandbox/docker
/sandbox/docker/certs:
domain.crt
domain.key

/sandbox/docker/registry:
config.yml
```

my `config.yml` file:

```
$ cat /sandbox/docker/registry/config.yml
version: 0.1
log:
    level: debug
    formatter: text
    fields:
        service: registry
        environment: prod
storage:
    s3:
        accesskey: awsaccesskey
        secretkey: awssecretkey
        region: us-west-1
        bucket: bucket
        encrypt: true
        secure: true
        v4auth: true
        chunksize: 5242880
        rootdirectory: /s3/object/name/prefix
    cache:
        layerinfo: inmemory
auth:
    token:
        realm: token-realm
        service: token-service
        issuer: registry-token-issuer
        rootcertbundle: /root/certs/bundle
http:
    addr: localhost:5000
    secret: myspecialsecret
    tls:
        certificate: /go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/certs/domain.crt
        key: /go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/certs/domain.key
    debug:
        addr: localhost:5001
```

certification files:

```
$ grep -r "^----" /sandbox/docker/certs/
/sandbox/docker/certs/domain.crt:-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
/sandbox/docker/certs/domain.crt:-----END CERTIFICATE-----
/sandbox/docker/certs/domain.crt:-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
/sandbox/docker/certs/domain.crt:-----END CERTIFICATE-----
/sandbox/docker/certs/domain.key:-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
/sandbox/docker/certs/domain.key:-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

where `domain.crt` holds also intermediate certificate (concatenated at the bottom).

**can anyone please point what is wrong?**

i know i can build a new registry image, as shown on [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/), but i'd like to do it only with `docker run` without `docker build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known to happen when the wrong S3 region is specified in the configuration file. See a similar report here: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/854

Comment: The S3 region in the config file must match the S3 region in which the bucket was originally created, otherwise registry will use the wrong URL and get a 301 redirect from AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a similar issue, problem in that one was using wrong s3 region for the bucket:
https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/issues/51